# Can’t update Windows 10. I tried every solution online but none is working

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

Each time I try to update Windows 10 it gives me this error massage.
I tried to find solution online on YouTube but none of them worked so far.

[image]

Comment: hi - I assume you are in fact connected to the internet, as I'm guessing your YouTube research was done from the same machine. Have you tried restarting the computer?

Comment: yes i restarted my pc many times

Comment: There will be install logs in new folders created on the C drive, they will be in the Panther sub folder, read the logs for clues.

Comment: how many days has the problem persisted?

Comment: normally i update my pc when there is a new update but it has been like half a month since the last update so i found it kind weird so i tried to update my pc manually but i just discovered today that the reason that i am not getting any updates because of this problem

Comment: Please provide us your Windows Update log.  How you generate this log (text) is well documented.

Comment: Do not tell us you've tried many solutions, instead tell us ALL of the solutions you have tried so we know what not to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble of any kind with Windows Update, you may run the [Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter) from Microsoft.

There are links to different versions of the troubleshooter for download from the linked page, including a version for Windows 10.

The page also contains further links giving more information on troubleshooting Windows Update if you still need it after running the tool.